# Difference between of and for

Tags: difference

Which one is correct of or for.
May Allah make you an obedient child for/of your parents.
Any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*Grammatically* there is nothing to prefer one over the other. Either is acceptable as an English sentence. The specific meaning will depend on context.

Someone who is obedient *for* their parents is obedient for them, but nothing is said about obedience in regard to anybody else. Maybe they totally ignore instructions from other people.

Someone who is a child of their parents, and also has the characteristic of obedience, is generally obedient. Or, in context, it might mean that, of several children of these parents, this one is an obedient one.

Answer (score 0):

"For" gives purpose.  It is asking God to make the child obedient, so that the parents will benefit.

"Of" indicates possession (in a wide sense) It could be used to clarify the meaning of "child" as being particularly a member of a family, and not just a young person.

It is also possible that this is an attempt to express "make you a child who is obedient of your parents". That would make you obey your parents (but not other people)  If that is the intention, it has been phrased ambiguously.